# Line-breaking unformatted URLs that contain no hyphens

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, urls

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
https://path.to.really.long/url/that/contains/no/dashes/but/instead/a/whole/lot/of/forward/slashes/which/makes/it/exceed/the/page/width
\end{document}
```

Using XeLaTeX, I am trying to use a large number of unformatted URLs *without* using the `hyperref` package, and would like the URLs to break at `/`, as some of them don’t contain `-`. How could I do this?

EDIT:

I’ll try to be more specific. What I have is this:

```
http://link1.com/long/link/...
‹lots of random text›
http://link2.com/long/link/...
‹lots of random text›
http://link3.com/long/link/...
...
‹lots of random text›
...
http://link573.com/long/link/...
```

It’s a team project, and I want the source to be able to be read, edited and *easily understood* by others who don’t use TeX. I have a master preamble/layout document and there I include all the other unformatted plaintext files.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `url` package, though?

Comment: Sure, the only constraint is that all the links should be in a roman font (and preferably not be clickable if that’s possible).

Comment: By "roman" font, do you mean the serif font that's used as the main font of the document?

Comment: Exactly! The links are entered without formatting in the source.

Comment: You've informed us that `\url{...}` is not acceptable because your co-authors "don't use TeX". What typesetting system *do* they use? Would they truly be unduly burdened by the occasional bit of TeX-style markup?

Comment: Believe me, I share your view on this. I would like to be able to just use the markup everywhere, but things are the way they are. I guess I’ll try to talk them over!

But it *is* rather strange that TeX doesn’t support this basic feature “natively”, no? Just being able to specify an additional hyphenation characters globally would be sufficient.

Comment: Incidentally, is compiling via LuaLaTeX an option, or does it have to be XeLaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: Any LaTeX derivative is fine! I tried LuaLaTeX for this purpose a bit earlier and got improved results, although not optimal. The URLs protruded an inch or so until they automatically hyphenated, and when I tried to copy the link from the resulting pdf, I got a hyphen followed by a space in the middle of the link. Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I've posted a new solution that uses LuaLaTeX to automatically replace all occurrences of `/` in the input with `\slash `. Note that LaTeX can't really do much about getting nice line lengths if the URL strings has only few and far-between slash symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you allowed to load the `url` package, though? If so, encase the URL in a `\url{...}` macro. Issue the instruction `\urlstyle{rm}` to ensure that the font used for the URL string is the same as the main text font.

The following code compiles equally well under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{rm} % roman font
\begin{document}
\noindent
\url{https://path.to.really.long/url/that/contains/no/dashes/but/instead/a/whole/lot/of/forward/slashes/which/makes/it/exceed/the/page/width}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX is an option for you, you could define a Lua function (to be registered with the `process_input_buffer` callback) that replaces all occurrences of `/` with `\slash`: The TeX macro `\slash`, unsurprisingly, inserts a slash symbol while allowing a line break immediately following this symbol. (The function also takes care not to allow a line break after the first of two consecutive `/` symbols, as such cases may occur quite frequently, viz., `\http://` and `\https://`.)

I trust this setup meets your objective of not having to encase URL strings in `\url` directives and still get line breaks following slash symbols.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local function slash_to_slash ( ll )
      ll = string.gsub ( ll, "/", "\\slash " )
      ll = string.gsub ( ll, "\\slash \\slash ", "/\\slash " )
      return ll
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", 
     slash_to_slash, 
     "convert slash symbols to slash macros")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}

https://path.to.really.long/url/that/contains/no/dashes/but/instead/a/whole/lot/of/forward/slashes/which/makes/it/exceed/the/page/width

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no way to just have a document of links lacking formatting, and have them appear as normal text, and breaking as normal text?

Comment: @svenper - I'm not sure I follow you. The URL string is rendered as "normal text", and as far as I can tell there's no special formatting applied to the URL string.

Comment: I’ll update the OP with more info.